# Is there ESlint rule that would right align keys and left align values of object?

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc

I found a rule that does this:

```
obj = {
  a      : 1,
  longkey: 2,
  zxc    : 3
}
```

which kinda sucks as you really loose track which value belongs to which key if one of the keys are long enough...

however if there was something like this...

```
obj = {
        a: 1,
  longkey: 2,
      zxc: 3
}
```

This i think would be ideal.

Comment: Looking for a library (that's what eslint plugins are) is off-topic on SO. If you could however try to modify the rule you found and post your attempt at patching it, we can probably help you to integrate a configuration option for the desired result.

Comment: I was told on eslint issue tracker to post here. I tried reading how to make new rules and I've no idea, that is 30 pages long booklet